# What all details does external system required to connect to salesforce REST resource

Tags: rest-api

I have created Rest resource in salesforce, this rest resource will be used by external system to push data into salesforce. What all details does external system required to connect to salesforce REST resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to create a Connected App in Salesforce (well, there is a way to go about this without a connected app, but it's not good practice so I won't be going over it).

That Connected App has some details like the *consumer key* and *consumer secret*. These are used to authenticate with Salesforce via OAuth 2.0. The precise details of what information you'll need depend on which [OAuth flow](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.remoteaccess_oauth_flows.htm&type=5) you end up using. The Web server flow and JWT Bearer flow are probably the two most common. Avoid the username-password flow if possible.

The general approach here is:

1. Go through an OAuth 2.0 flow
2. Receive an access token
3. Make your actual request (to your REST service) and include your access token in the "Authorization" header